# Specific value of a point on a time trajectory

Tags: differential-equations, time-series

I have two equations. I want to evaluate the time series at a given point. So here, I want to know for a given set of values `Vals` what's the value at t = 700. How do I find that?

```
Val = {f1 --> 10, f2 --> 5, a1 -> 1, a2 ->0.3}
dN1 = N1'[t] == (f1 * N1[t]) - a1 * N1[t]
dN2 = N2'[t] == (f2 * N2[t])-  a2 * N2[t]
```

---

I tried the solution suggested by @Nasser but it doesn't seem to work for the original problem. I'm posting the code for the original here.

```
Pars = {fin1 -> 0.9, fin2 -> 0.4, en1 -> 3.55, en2 -> 3.4, ein1 -> 3, 
   ein2 -> 4.7, fn2 -> 7.2, h -> 3.2, e1 -> 2.5, mi -> 0.4, mn -> 0.8,
    fe -> 7.8, r -> 3.7, S -> 5.5, fn1 -> 7.96}; 
dImm = Imm'[
    t] == (ein1*fin1*En[t]*Imm[t]*N1[t] + 
       ein2*fin2*En[t]*Imm[t]*N2[t])/e1 - mi * Imm[t];
dN1 = N1'[t] == (fn1 * En[t] * N1[t])/en1 - fin1*Imm[t]*N1[t] - 
    mn * N1[t];
dN2 = N2'[t] == (fn2 * En[t] * N2[t])/en2 - fin2*Imm[t]*N2[t] - 
    mn * N2[t];
dEn = En'[t] == (fe*S/(h + S)) - r*En[t] - 
    ein1*fin1*En[t]*Imm[t]*N1[t] - ein2*fin2*En[t]*Imm[t]*N2[t] - 
    fn1*En[t]*N1[t] - fn2*En[t]*N2[t];

ic = {Imm[500] == 0.0001, N1[500] == 0.01, N2[500] == 1.29, 
  En[500] == 0.37}
sol = DSolveValue[{dImm, dN1, dN2, dEn, ic}, {Imm[t], N1[t], N2[t], 
    En[t]}, t];
sol /. Pars /. t -> 700
```

Error: DSolveValue::dsvar: The variable specification is not valid.

Comment: @cvgmt I modified the equations a bit. This should help

Comment: Is there specific reason where your initial conditions start at time t=500 and not at zero as normally the case?

Comment: fyi, updated for the new system you posted. But I made initial conditions start at t=0. You can change that if you want.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know for a given set of values Vals what's the value at t =
> 700

If I understood you right, then one way is to solve the ode's and then replace the values in the solution. But you need some initial conditions

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Val = {f1 -> 10, f2 -> 5, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0.3}
dN1 = N1'[t] == (f1*N1[t]) - a1*N1[t]
dN2 = N2'[t] == (f2*N2[t]) - a2*N2[t]
ic = {N1[0] == 1, N2[0] == 3}; (*change as needed*)
sol = DSolveValue[{dN1, dN2, ic}, {N1[t], N2[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now replace with `Val` and the actual time `t` to evaluate

```
sol /. Val /. t -> 70
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Repeat for different time:

```
sol /. Val /. t -> 3
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update for new equations**

The new equations updated in the original question can't be solved analytically so numerical solution is needed:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Pars = {fin1 -> 0.9, fin2 -> 0.4, en1 -> 3.55, en2 -> 3.4, ein1 -> 3, 
   ein2 -> 4.7, fn2 -> 7.2, h -> 3.2, e1 -> 2.5, mi -> 0.4, mn -> 0.8,
    fe -> 7.8, r -> 3.7, S -> 5.5, fn1 -> 7.96};
dImm = Imm'[
    t] == (ein1*fin1*En[t]*Imm[t]*N1[t] + 
       ein2*fin2*En[t]*Imm[t]*N2[t])/e1 - mi*Imm[t];
dN1 = N1'[t] == (fn1*En[t]*N1[t])/en1 - fin1*Imm[t]*N1[t] - mn*N1[t];
dN2 = N2'[t] == (fn2*En[t]*N2[t])/en2 - fin2*Imm[t]*N2[t] - mn*N2[t];
dEn = En'[t] == (fe*S/(h + S)) - r*En[t] - 
    ein1*fin1*En[t]*Imm[t]*N1[t] - ein2*fin2*En[t]*Imm[t]*N2[t] - 
    fn1*En[t]*N1[t] - fn2*En[t]*N2[t];

ic = {Imm[0] == 0.0001, N1[0] == 0.01, N2[0] == 1.29, En[0] == 0.37}
odes = {dImm, dN1, dN2, dEn, ic} /. Pars;
 sol = NDSolveValue[{odes, ic}, {Imm, N1, N2, En}, {t, 0, 500}, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can obtain the values for different times:

```
time = 10;
sol[[#]][time] & /@ Range[Length@sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And

```
time = 300;
sol[[#]][time] & /@ Range[Length@sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I tried the solution to my original code. But the error says `The variable specification is not valid`

Comment: @Biotechgeek  I could only try/use what was posted. I'll try to see what it does not work on your new system which is more complicated, but no guarantees.